# Same Spatial Query on nodes table gives different read time

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgis

I have created 2 databases.

1. First one has PGSnapshot Schema which looks like this.
   [image: pgnsapshot schema]

On this I fire query

```
select id,ST_AsText(geom)
from nodes
where
ST_Intersects(geom , ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-125.59390619 46.536192670000005, -125.59390619 49.00241116, -117.19116211 49.00241116, -117.19116211 46.536192670000005, -125.59390619 46.536192670000005))',4326));
```

Total query runtime: 15 min 28 secs. 26732975 rows affected.
Analyze for this query is:
[image]

2. Second is a schema created with just nodes/ways/relations table with just geometry column and id column as shown in this picture.(properties column is empty)
   [image]

When I fire the same query, the result is different.

```
select id,ST_AsText(geom)
from nodes
where
ST_Intersects(geom , ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-125.59390619 46.536192670000005, -125.59390619 49.00241116, -117.19116211 49.00241116, -117.19116211 46.536192670000005, -125.59390619 46.536192670000005))',4326));
```

Total query runtime: 5 min 6 secs. 25624080 rows affected.
Analyze for this query is:
[image]

Only difference between the first and second table is that first schema has index on geometry column of nodes table and the second schema does not have any index on geometry column in nodes data. But due to index, the read time should be more as compared to the indexed schema.

I am trying to understand what could be the reason for this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The different counts indicate that the data are different. But without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output nothing definitive can be answered.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe updated description with analyze.

Comment: Also, [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242918/query-performance-of-index-scans-slower-than-parallel-seq-scan-on-postgres) looks somewhat similar to my problem.

Comment: More images. That puts me off. Please use formatted text. Besides, that's not `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output.

Comment: Your first query plan show it taking just over 5 minutes, not 15 minutes.

Comment: Yea, but if you compare the query plan with 2nd analyze, you can see the execution time is more in 1st, and that there is parallel seq scan happening in 2nd whereas 1st one is doing index scan.